# Do action until specific time in C#

Tags: c#, time, nxt

I'm trying to develop a Windows Phone application that runs a motor. I want to execute the `MoveCar` method only for 1 second and then `Stop`.

I have this code that works correctly to move the C motor:

```
CarControl _cc;    
private void UP_Motor_C(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _cc.Turn = 50; //the C motor will start running in 50% speed
        _cc.LeftSpeed = 0; //the B motor will stop working
        _cc.RightSpeed = 0; //the A motor will stop working

        _cc.MoveCar();
    }
```

My problem is that I'm missing a code to start `MoveCar` only for one second. What is the best way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I'm guessing there is something in the NXT framework that will do that for you...

Comment: Asking for code and showing no effort gets you down voted.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Take a look at the tour before you move for one second and then stop! http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    _cc.Turn = 50; //the C motor will start running in 50% speed

    _cc.LeftSpeed = 0; //the B motor will stop working
    _cc.RightSpeed = 0; //the A motor will stop working

    _cc.MoveCar();

    System.Threading.Thread.Current.Sleep(1000);
```